# How Chrome's Developer Tools force element state? How can I do the same using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

I'm working on SPA (with Angular 4) and want to put sliding underline menu inside my popup window, just like [this one](https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon).

However this is not page menu so the active state cannot be based on the route. The first element will be the default one when popup is opened.
What I'm trying to achieve is to use JavaScript to set second, third, etc. element to active, so once clicked on second item, it would get underlined.
My code is pretty much the same, all I did is added :active state.

```
.two:hover ~ hr, .two:active ~ hr  {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr, .three:active ~ hr  {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr, .four:active ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
```

Does anyone know how Chrome's Developer Tools change to state to "active"?
Ideally there would be some JavaScript function to do exactly the same so I could simply call it when click function is triggered.

Any help to achieve that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it'll work, but try using `$("button").focus()`. Optmize the selector accordingly, of course.

Comment: use `.active` instead，`.two:hover ~ hr, .two:active ~ hr,.two.hover ~ hr, .two.active ~ hr   {`

Comment: I've tried focus() and it doesn't work. I'll try using .active

Comment: Perfect, it works just great!

Comment: Though I'm still interested if anyone knows how developer tools do it?